# How to get images to load/open in a div layer like a html page using ajax code .load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, html

I have this code that i have copied idrectly from w3schools to test it out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("images/sketchbook/thumb/babymat_thumb.jpg");
  });
});
```

to get an image opening up in another div. It works with a html document but I was wondering if this code could be modified to open up an image? Anything I try to do to it doesn't seem to be working. (instead I get a bunch of code, like when you open up an image in Notepad or Word or whatever)

**RESOLVED** - I used to 'append' code given below but ended the img src with "> rather than " /> because it wouldnt work otherwise

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").append('<img src="images/sketchbook/thumb/babymat_thumb.jpg" />');
  });
});
```

Comment: ah thank you both! the 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").append('<img src="images/sketchbook/thumb/babymat_thumb.jpg" />');
  });
});

only worked when I took out the '/' ending the image.

Comment: it should be working as provided, check this sample http://jsbin.com/oPUZUn/2/ , and if it works plz mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to load the image 'smoothly/on the fly', try

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("button").click (function() {
    $("#div1").append('<img src="img/01/02/example.png" />');
  });
});
```

IF you're trying to load it via AJAX, remember. For security purposes you can only load content off of the SAME DOMAIN. Since you're developing locally, you can't use your local file protocol. Try the following.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("button").click( function( ){
    $("#div1").load("file:///C:/Users/NOPE/Desktop/photo%203.JPG");
  });
});
```